# MessageBox Features in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, messagebox

I am trying to create a MessageBox that appears at the start of my program, asking the user if they would like to load a file or not. So far I have:

```
public static void LoadFile(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Would you like to load a file?",
    System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo, System.Windows.MessageBoxQuestion);

    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        // cancel the closure of the form.
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

I realize that some of this code is used to exit out of the program. I don't intend to do this, it is just currently still left in from the sample code I was trying. When I try this code, I receive several errors, the major one involves the `MessageBoxQuestion`. The error reads

> The type or namespace name 'MessageBoxQuestion' does not exist in the namespace System.Windows

I previously had this error on the `MessageBoxButtons` but fixed it by changing it to `MessageBoxButton`. Starting with just a simple message box, I originally had the code:

```
public static void LoadFile()
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Text");
}
```

This worked perfectly fine, despite the fact that I had to add the `System.Windows.` to remove the error

> The name MessageBox does not exist in the current context.

Does anyone know a solution as to how I can get my `MessageBox` working correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The WPF version of `MessageBox` differs from the Windows Forms' version. You need to use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598709(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally came up with:

```
public static void LoadFile()
    {
        // Configure message box 
        string message = "Would you like to load a file?";
        string caption = "Startup";
        System.Windows.MessageBoxButton buttons = System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
        System.Windows.MessageBoxImage icon = System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Information;
        // Show message box
        System.Windows.MessageBoxResult result = 
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon);
        if(result == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {

        }
        else if(result == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.No)
        {

        }
   }
```

I included the if else branch that I planned to use later.